# JavaScript caching, Rails and Apache passenger?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching, capistrano

I have written a Capistrano recipe to remove the `all.js` cached JavaScript file and tell the server to restart, but it still doesn't work right. And inevitably I have to go manually delete the `all.js` file and then manually restart Apache. (touching restart.txt doesn't always work).

Anybody have a working solution to this problem?

Here is the current recipe:

```
desc "Package Javascripts"  
    task :package_javascripts, :roles => :web do
      sudo %{rm -f #{current_path}/public/javascripts/all.js}
      javascripts.each do |javascript|
        run %{/usr/bin/ruby #{current_path}/lib/jsmin.rb < \
              #{current_path}/public/javascripts/#{javascript}.js >> \
              #{current_path}/public/javascripts/all.js}
      end
      run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you linked you task somewhere:

```
after "deploy:symlink", :package_javascripts
```

Also change restart line to:

```
run "rm -f #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt ; touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
```